# ASP.NET MVC Form loaded via .ascx & ajax submits multiple times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have Resorts.aspx which loads content from ResortProducts.ascx into a div via Ajax.

## Resorts.aspx

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            // View Resort Rates >>
            $('.ViewResortRatesLink').click(function () {
                var sID = getQueryStringParameterByName("sID", this.href);
                sID = sID.replace("~", "");
                renderCart("div" + sID, "Loading Resort Product Information...");
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    success: function (result) {
                        renderCart("div" + sID, result)
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

        function renderCart(container, data) {
            $("#" + container).html(data);
        }
```

Here is the code for ActionLink which triggers above jQuery:

```
                        <%= Html.ActionLink(
                                    "View Resort Rates >>",
                                    "ResortProducts", 
                                    "Resorts",
                                    new { sID = _supplier.SupplierID },
                                    new { @class = "ViewResortRatesLink" })%>
```

Here is the Div:

```
<div id="div<% =ResortSupplierID %>"></div>
```

ResortProducts.ascx loads list of Resort products, each product contains its own form using which the product can be added to shopping cart.

## ResortProducts.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TrlSite.Services.ViewModels.ResortsView>" %>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //+ Add to cart
            $(".addProductToCartForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var HiddenCartForm = {
                    SupplierID: $(this.hSupplierID).val(),
                    Code: $(this.hProductCode).val(),
                };
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), HiddenCartForm, function (data) {
                    renderCart("rightColumn", data)
                });
                return false; // form already submitted using ajax, don't submit it again the regular way 
            });
        });

        function renderCart(container, data) {
            $("#" + container).html(data);
        } 
    </script>

<% foreach (var _supplier in Model.resorts) { %>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="tb_PAL">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
                    <td>ROOM TYPE</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center">PRICE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
                </tr>
                <% 
                    foreach (var _product in products)
                    { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><% = _product.Description %></td>
                        <td  align="left">
                            <% using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "addProductToCartForm" }))
                                { %>
                                <input type="hidden" name="hSupplierID" id="hSupplierID" value="<% = _supplier.SupplierID %>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="hProductCode" id="hProductCode" value="<% = _product.Code %>" />
                                <input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
                            <% } %>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" align="center">
                            <span id="roomprice_" onclick="return false;" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;color:#000000">
                                $<% = _product.TotalPrice %>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% } %>    
                <tr >                       
                    <td colspan="4">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><hr /></td>
    </tr>                   
</table>
<% } %>
```

There could be multiple "View Resort Rates >>" links in Resorts.aspx, clicking on each link will load ResortProducts.ascx containing corresponding list of products.  If I load ResortProducts.ascx only once in Resorts.aspx and click on submit button everything works fine. It posts the form once. But if I load .ascx multiple times then the form gets submitted number of times .ascx is loaded. How can I resolve this issue? When I am submit a form, it should be posted only once and at the same time I should be able to post multiple forms.

Comment: I was looking at this wrong and I don't believe I'm right with my answer so I deleted it. Sorry about that. I'll keep looking at it and if I have another idea I'll post it.

Comment: Dusty, You were correct with your solution of moving the javascript out of the .ascx file. Now I have it all working. I moved the javascript into a seperate .js file and referenced it into parent .aspx file and also used "jquery.live('click', function (e))" function to bind all forms generated by .ascx file into div's contained by parent .aspx file. The last piece we were missing was binding all dynamically generated forms by using .live() function. Its now working as desired. Thanks for your patience and guiding me in right direction.

Comment: Ok, I undeleted my answer in case others have a similar issue. I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, I believe that if you add this control multiple times then the javascript section will also be created several times. Check to see if that is occurring and if it is then I believe that the best way would be to put the javascript section in its own js file and then reference the javascript file once in the page that will contain the controls. I hope this helps.

Comment: Dusty, I tried your suggestion but it didn't help. I see same behaviour even after moving the javascript to its own .js file.

Comment: Is your reference to it in the partial view or in the parent view? If in the partial view then I believe it will be the same as if you had the javascript in the partial view so double check to make sure it is in the parent view an only rendering the function once. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: The reference is in the partial view. I had tried to keep it in the parent view initially but then the funtion call from .ascx is not getting fired. How can I have the Script (or reference) in .aspx and have the .ascx trigger that?

Comment: You should just be able to use it as you normally would. The best way to see what is going on is to open the source of the page in the browser or you a developer tool like Firebug. When you have the javascript in the main view it should only show up once, but if you have it in the partial view it will show up for every instance of the partial view. So if you call the function, there are actually several functions that are getting called. I hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason, when I reference the .js file in .ascx, form submit triggers the jquery function defined in .js file BUT if I reference the .js file in parent .aspx file, form submit directly goes to my controller by passing the jquery logic. Any idea why this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe try just putting the function in the parent page instead of the separate file. Once you get that working you can re-investigate putting it in a separate file. The separate file I believe is the correct approach, but getting it to work is more important. :)

Comment: Dusty, I had already tried putting the function in parent page and it didn't work... so I guess external .js file is not an issue. Its .ascx not triggering jquery function call if the function is not defined inside .ascx. I am trying to use jquery.live() to bind submit events defined in .ascx to see if it helps...something like this "$(".addProductToCartForm").live('submit', function (e) {" but no luck so far... :(

Comment: Were you able to make sure that your references to jquery and your javascript looked correct in the source of the browser? Does javascript work in the page at all? Try to put an alert in the document.ready of your javascript on the main page to make sure. Let me know. We'll get it figured out. :)

Comment: Dusty, Thx for your patience with this issue. The only way this functionality is working (though incorrectly) is if I have the jquery function related to form submition inside .ascx file. If I move the function to parent .aspx file, its not getting triggered on form submition. Also, I analyzed the code in firebug and I am able to see HTML generated by .ascx file BUT not the jquery script generated by .ascx unless I am not looking at correct place.

Comment: Dusty, You were correct with your solution of moving the javascript out of the .ascx file. Now I have it all working. I moved the javascript into a seperate .js file and referenced it into parent .aspx file and also used "jquery.live('click', function (e))" function to bind all forms generated by .ascx file into div's contained by parent .aspx file. The last piece we were missing was binding all dynamically generated forms by using .live() function. Its now working as desired. Thanks for your patience and guiding me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I just read the same answer in the comments of the initial post...

---

I know this post is getting old, but I have been through a similar problem. First, I am using .NET 3.5, MVC 2.0, jQuery 1.8, bootstrap 2.0. The partial view I am referencing to is actually a user control (ascx) representing a form with a few fields and validation that is opened as a modal dialog.

Second, here is what I did:

- I moved the javascript file of the partial view (user control) to the parent view, because it was called several times even on a single call of the partial view.
- But then, the jQuery bindings inside the partial view stopped to work, because the javascript was executed before the content of the partial view was loaded.
- The solution I found was to modify the binding types to use jQuery live bindings, and it worked.

I hope that it will help someone else!